# Regex for digits and dob

Tags: regex

I am learning regex and don't know much about it. Can someone please tell me what is
the proper regex for:

1. Exactly 4 digits (`1234`)
2. Two digits followed by a slash, then two digits followed by other slash and 4 more digits for date of birth (`01/01/1983`)

Comment: Since you're learning, you must have tried something, right? How about showing us what you have tried?

Comment: 1.`^\d{4}$` 2.don't parse date with regex..Also what have you tried..which language are you using

Comment: Mate, this exact question has been asked about 1000000 times already on SO... please take a look

Answer (score 1):

1. Exactly 4 digits:

   ```
   \d{4}
   ```
2. Two digits followed by a slash two digits followed by 4 digits for date of birth:

   ```
   \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
   ```

Depending on your use case you may want to add beginning and end of string anchors (`^` and `$` respectively).  For example the regex `^\d{4}$` would match the string `1234`, but would not match any part of the string `foo 1234`.  If you wanted to make the digits from `foo 1234` you could just use the regex `\d{4}`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language, but here's the relevant code for javascript:

1) Exactly four digits, with nothing else:

```
^\d{4}$
```

2) Two digits followed by a slash two digits followed by 4 digits

```
^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$
```

^ = string must start with this 
$ = string must end with this 
{n} = where n is the number of times this should be repeated 
\d = special escape character for digits

check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)out for more info